# Jein - a regionalism or the German-wide jargon?

Tags: word-usage, regional

I'm currently in Bavaria and I often hear the word **jein**, which means that answer could be either yes or no, depending what aspects are taken into account:

> - Hast du das schon gemacht?
> - Jein. Es funktioniert zwar, aber nicht für alle Fälle.

Is this a Bavarian regionalism, or is it a jargon word known German-wide?

Comment: Just a note on the side: I'd personally write it `jain`, since it mixes `Ja` and `Nein`.

Comment: @Lukas: von der Aussprache her trifft's aber *jein* besser.

Comment: According to dictionaries, there is no choice - the only correct way of spelling it is "jein".

Comment: Well, I've just learnt something :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the song called ['Jein' by a combo called 'Fettes Brot'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcV7VN3l3bY) (what actually means 'fat bread') from Hamburg. The refrain goes somehow like 'Soll ich's wirklich machen oder lass ich's lieber sein? JEIN!' and the whole song is about wether to take a chance or not. Like that: 'Girlfriend is somewhere else over the weekend. Some other girl you always found sexy asks you to spend the night with her' and then the refrain again: 'Soll ich's wirklich machen oder lass ich's lieber sein? JEIN!'

What I'm driving at is: That song was very big in the charts (Top 10) when it came out in 1996. It went on nearly every pop radio station up and down for a long time all over the country. Nowadays being a DJ and playing that song on a wedding or a birthday party is a sure guarantee to get everybody aged between 8 and 88 on the dancefloor trying to sing along. So I think that word found it's way in nearly everybody's word pool from north to south and east to west and is normally used to get the chance to specify your answer on a yes-or-no question which you don't want or don't can simply answer with 'Ja' or 'Nein'.

That word even has an [entry in Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jein). And not to forget the [Duden entry](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/jein).

Comment: I never heard of that song, but *jein* has of course become a normal word of the German standard language often replacing "ja und nein". Among others, it is extremely convenient for journalists, who can now write things such as "Diese Frage ist mit einem klaren Jein zu beantworten." So it's not surprising [that it spread](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=klares+Jein&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cklares%20Jein%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 16):

Es ist nicht regional begrenzt, sondern wird bundesweit benutzt.

Comment: Also als Österreicher würd' ich einmal sagen dass "bundesweit" immer noch regional begrenzt ist ;-) Aber im Ernst: auch in Österreich ist dieser Begriff bekannt.

Comment: Nun, begrenzt wäre es, wenn ich gesagt hätte `ist auf das Bundesgebiet` (wessen - der Schweiz?) beschränkt. Da fällt mir ein: Österreich hat doch auch einen BUndeskanzler, ist also auch ein Bundesstaat. Zurück zum Haupteinwand: Dass es bundesweit benutzt wird bedeutet nicht, dass es außerhalb nicht benutzt wird. Wenn ich sage "Deine Mutter hat Flöhe" sage ich damit ja auch nicht, dass Dein Hund keine hat.

Comment: @userunknown: Wieso argumentierst du wie man es auslegen könnte, sodass es Österreicht miteinschließt, wenn du es offensichtlich nicht so gemeint hattest?

Comment: @NickKidman: Die Frage war, ob es ein bajuwarischer Regionalismus sei, oder deutschlandweit benutzt wird. Ich glaube meine Antwort geht auf genau diese Frage ein. Die Frage auf den ganzen deutschsprachigen Raum auszudehnen begrüße ich, kann aber selbst keine Antwort dazu geben. Da mir Joachim mit Fragen der wörtlichen Auslegung kommt reagiere ich entsprechend.